# too many connections for role "username" heroku nodejs - what is yobuko?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I have two sites that started receiving the too many connections for role error.

The site crashes several times a day with that error and the only thing that helps is the cli `heroku pg:killall`

The application releases all the connections correctly - it's a very simple and basic application that uses postgres connection pool.

When I look at the open sessions on pgadmin I see multiple connections by something called "yobuko".

[image]

As I follow it, it opens more and more connections until it reaches the 20 connections limit and crashes my application.

What is yobuko, who let it into my database, and how can I stop it from killing my site?

With the lack of a better answer - I'll write a script that hunts these connections and kill them every couple of minutes.

I'm using hobby-dev database level that according to [this article on heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans) should work as long as I accept up to 4 hours downtime per month (that's ok for me)

EDIT:
As I had the Yobuko connections, I also started having other connections called "puma: cluster worker XX."

The last sql they run is:

```
SELECT "oid", "typname" FROM "pg_type" WHERE (("typtype" = 'b') AND 
("typname" IN ('hstore')))
```

Here's a screen shot:
[image]

Comment: Yobuko is an internal Heroku system that manages databases - you should open a support ticket for us to take a look.

Comment: Hi, I did 626237
I got brushed of by someone named Tim telling me that "One of the limitations of the hobby tier databases is unannounced maintenance. Many hobby databases run on a single shared server, and we will occasionally need to restart that server for hardware maintenance purposes, or migrate databases to another server for load balancing. When that happens, you'll see an error in your logs or have problems connecting. If the server is restarting, it might take 15 minutes or more for the database to come back online."

Comment: Yeah my app also seem to suffer from this yobuko now - at least it does reach 19 connections sometimes during last couple days. Maybe Heroku employs `yobuko` more these days because they're investigating https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1625 incident starting from Sept 4. Looks like a `heroku pg:kill` - based script against yobuko will be helpful, yeah.

Comment: Yep - currently my site needs killall every couple of hours - so it's not really useful. My users are not happy :)
I'm in touch with the support for a week now - they are still on it, and my site is still mostly down.
I'm hopeful that it's temporary and they'll get it done soon.
I wonder why it's not mentioned and status.heroku.com as it seems pretty wide

Comment: @ArtemVasiliev are you using the eu database or the US?
The support told me it was eu only.

Comment: @Noam yeah EU but it became allright for me after that initial killall - maybe I'm just more lucky. All I saw is up to 4 yobukos after then ) Figured a script to start with btw - `heroku run -- rails runner "puts User.connection.select_rows(%Q(SELECT pid FROM pg_stat_activity where datname = 'YOUR_DB_ID' and application_name = 'yobuko')).flatten.to_json"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was a problem with Heroku from 5/9/2018 to 13/9/2018 with their eu hobby dev databases.
Their internal tools had a connection leak that opened connections with appname `yobuku` and with another appname called `puma cluster worker`.

The only out was to manually kill these connections every few hours.

The problem seems to be resolved now.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. Heroku got back to me with the tip to use `select pg_terminate_backend(sub1.pid) from (select pid from pg_stat_activity where application_name = 'yobuko' and state = 'idle') as sub1;` to kill the idle connections selectively. I’ll try to combine it with the scheduler plugin to run it automatically.

The reason is a malfunction of a monitoring tool they’re using for hobby tier databases (maybe implying that the standard tier and above are not affected). They’re working on a fix but don’t have a timeline yet.

Comment: Are you using the EU datacenter or the US? The support told me that it was eu only

Comment: @Noam Yep, an EU datacenter.