# Heroku postgres, unwanted "puma: cluster worker" connections to my database

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I have several heroku sites with postgres database.
The site is based on node.js - nothing else at the server side.

As I look in my PgAdmin open sessions I see 4 connections called `puma: cluster worker #: 17 [app]` (# is number)

They are idle but are open for many hours and the number of connections is growing. taking up more and more of my available 20 connections in the `hobby-dev` plan.

The last sql they run is:

`SELECT "oid", "typname" FROM "pg_type" WHERE (("typtype" = 'b') AND ("typname" IN ('hstore')))`

Here's a screen shot:
[image]

What are they and why do I need them?

EDIT:
As time goes by it's getting worst:
[image]

Comment: This was a temporary problem with heroku.
See:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52216471/too-many-connections-for-role-username-heroku-nodejs-what-is-yobuko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52216471/too-many-connections-for-role-username-heroku-nodejs-what-is-yobuko)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [too many connections for role "username" heroku nodejs - what is yobuko?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52216471/too-many-connections-for-role-username-heroku-nodejs-what-is-yobuko)